# Can't use OSX's php after removing homebrew's php

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

a few months ago, I installed php55 using homebrew. However, I don't need that anymore and want to use the php version that OS X ships itself.

So I uninstalled php55 using homebrew. When I run `php -v` now, the following error occurs:

```
/usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

When I run `ls /usr/local/bin | grep php` I see that no php executable is there anymore (as expected due to uninstalling the package).

When I run `echo $PATH`, it prints:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin
```

As far as I understand the usage of the PATH variable, the terminal should search in /usr/bin for an executable called `php` when there is no one in /usr/local/bin, but it doesn't. And removing /usr/local/bin from the PATH isn't an option as long as I have other homebrew packages installed on the system.

When running `which php` the output is as expected: /usr/bin/php, the php executable shipped by OS X.

Any suggestions why the shell doesn't find the php executable?

P.S. The details about the uninstalling of the php55 package:
I uninstalled php55, php55-intl and all of their dependencies that are not needed by any other package. Then I untaped homebrew-php.

My `brew doctor` output:

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    cloog018
    gmp4
    isl011
    libmpc08
    mpfr2
    zlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew prune` dit it ... Somewhere must have been a dead symlink that pointed to /usr/local/bin/php (which doesn't exist any more).

Even though the problem is solved now, I am really curious about why homebrew didn't do this during the uninstall process. Any suggestions?